# glTF exporter with images

Tags: texturing, export, gltf

I'm currently trying to import an exported .gltf into my program. I'm now at the point where I need the information of the image. But in the .gltf is no 'image' or 'texture' section, even if I check 'Embed images'.

In my test model I took just the default cube, unwrapped an uv map and painted the model. After all, I saved the image.

Am I completely mistaken in my procedure?

Ask me about any information you need, I'm not really familiar with blender, I'm just scratching its possibilities to create basic objects.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For a while there was a known issue in the original glTF exporter where it wouldn't export "packed" images (ones that exist only in Blender, not on disk, such as resulting from texture painting as you describe).  This is fixed in the newer glTF-Blender-IO project, that ships with Blender 2.80 Beta.